# Prevent iTunes from starting when iPhone is plugged in on Mac

Tags: mac, iphone, itunes

Is there any way to prevent iTunes from starting on a Mac under OS X Leopard when an iPhone is plugged in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Or open System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login Items and remove the "iTunesHelper" entry.

Comment: I figured that would do the trick, and it does. But I wondered if there was another way I was missing.

Comment: The other way would be to plug your iPod/iPhone and choose the device from the side panel. There make sure you are on the "Summary" tab and uncheck the option: "Automatically Sync when this ihone is connected". This method works only for your device and not for any other you might plug in, unless of course you uncheck that option for all of them.

Comment: I was able to prevent automatic syncing by deselecting the correct option in iTunes preferences, but iTunes itself would still start up (which slowed things down, used up memory, and generally was annoying).

Answer (score 3):

> Open iTunes> Preferences>Devices>General tab and check "prevent iPods [etc] from automatically syncing"

http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?t=157512

Comment: I don't see an 'iPod' preference page, perhaps that is on the Windows version.

Comment: The pane is called "Devices" on a mac.
The option is calles "Disable automatic syncing for iPhones and iPods".

Comment: I see. I already did disable synching, but iTunes itself still launched when the device was plugged in. True to its word though, it didn't sync.

Comment: I don't see this for iTunes v.9 on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't actually work; my apologies for editing and upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion this option has moved very slightly.  Find it under:

**System Preferences** -> **Users & Groups** -> **Login Items**

Then remove the **iTunesHelper** entry.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer it like this:

1. go to iTunes -> Preferences
2. select Device tab
3. check the prevent iPods,iPads from syncing automatically

This should solve this issue.