# Prevent iTunes from launching on Windows 7 startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, itunes, itunes-10

iTunes starts every time I boot my Windows 7 computer.  How can I prevent iTunes from starting on Windows startup?  Is there a simple setting or do I need to edit the Windows registry to accomplish this?

Comment: Try looking here? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html

Comment: yea, kind of a simple question for superuser.  I meant to post this on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ but I was in a hurry and accidently posted to superuser.com.  Would have been a good contribution to the apple knowledge base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to "Start"
2. Click on "Run"
3. In the Open box type "**msconfig**" and then click "**OK**"
4. Select the "**Startup**" tab at the top
5. De-select **iTunes** from the list and click "**Apply**" then "**OK**".

*You may need to restart your computer for this change to take effect.*

Comment: Have turned it off in msconfig AND ccleaner and it still starts up!

Answer (score 2):

If you do what wizlog suggested and iTunes is still starting automatically, it could be related to your iPod.  iTunes is set--by default--to automatically launch iTunes if it detects an iPod. There is a setting in iTunes, which disables this function.

**Edit:** This also includes iPhones and iPads too

Answer (score 0):

Since MSConfig has already been suggested I can advise you to try [CCleaner](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner), a freeware program for cleaning cookies and unnecessary data and with which you can also disable unneeded programs from starting up with a really simple dialogue.

What you [(also) need to disable](https://superuser.com/questions/55390/prevent-itunes-from-starting-when-iphone-is-plugged-in-on-windows) is iTunesHelper which boots up iTunes everytime it detects an iPod/iPhone plugged in. You will be able to find the entry for ituneshelper.exe if you use msconfig or any other start-up application manager.

[image: CCleaner]

Comment: Have turned it off in msconfig AND ccleaner and it still starts up!